# What's the difference between the code inside a finally clause and the code located after catch clause?

Tags: java, exceptions

My java code is just like below:

```
public void check()throws  MissingParamException{
    ......
}
public static void main(){
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        check();
    } catch (MissingParamException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        out.println("message:"+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        out.close();
    }finally{
        out.close();
    }
    //out.close();
}
```

Then, my confusion is: what the difference if I put `out.close()` in a finally code block or if I just remove finally code block and put `out.close()` behind catch clause (which has been commented in the code). I know that in both ways, the `out.close()` will be executed because I know that whether the exception happened, the code behind the catch clause will always be executed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `finally {}` block is *always* called (unless you call `exit()` before finally is reached - but you won't be doing that most of the time).

The purpose of finally is to clean up any resources allocated in the `try {}` block, even if something was thrown and it hit the `catch{}` block.

Consider the code:

```
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hello();
    }

    public static void hello() {
        try {
            System.out.println("hi");
            return;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        } finally {
            System.out.println("finally");
        }
    }
}
```

While there isn't any resource allocation in this, just pretend there is.  This will print out:

```
hi
finally
```

If you had opened a file in the try block, the finally is the place to clean it up.  If you had opened one file, and then tried to open another one (that threw an exception), the finally is the place to clean that up.

If there was an uncaught exception by the `catch` block, then the `finally` would run, and the exception would get passed on up.

Putting `out.close()` in the `catch` *and* the `finally` is redundant - because it will be run in the finally block - on a caught exception or successful completion of the `try`.

With the existing code, the following code paths are possible:

- No exception:

  1. check() - no exception thrown
  2. finally { } - out.close
- Caught exception:

  1. check() - MissingParamException thrown
  2. catch { } - stuff and out.close
  3. finally { } - out.close
- Uncaught exception:

  1. check() - NPE thrown
  2. finally { } - out.close

You should be able to see from this, the `finally` is always called, and in the caught exception, `out.close()` is invoked twice.

The associated spec is [§14.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2) in Java SE 7 language specification.

Answer (score 8):

The difference is that if your check() function throws any exception OTHER than MissingParamException, anything below try/catch will not get executed because your function's stack will get unrolled until a catch is found that will handle that exception of that type (or possibly thread exits if exception is not handled).  However, the code you put inside the finally clause is guaranteed to be executed no matter what happens inside the try block.

So in your case leaving out.close() inside the finally block would be a more correct thing to do.

Comment: Simple and to the point.

Answer (score 3):

Let's do the case analysis.

1. No exception thrown:
    No difference
2. MissingParamException thrown:
    No difference
3. Some exception you don't have a catch for i. e. Null Ref:
    If it is in the finally out.close() will be called.  If it is after everything then it will not be called.

   Incidentally you call close in the catch block and the finally block that means when a MissingParamException is thrown you call close twice.  Not a big deal, just not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Most has been answered in the other answers but one thing not:
If you choose to not use finally and your code goes into you catch block and there's another exception in your catch block then no close will be called at all.